# How ot obtain a listitem field using Linq

Tags: list, linq, sharepoint

I have a user group list and a SPList. I need to obtain the ID of the item that has the CreatorID (Column) equals to the user group ID.

I mean, in mi list I have 20 fields, with three coulmns, one of the is the field ID, other the name, and other the GroupID. Then... I have a user with all its groups.

I need to know which ID has the same GruopID on the list and on the user groups.

I have this, but I think that with linq it could be fast and a better way... But I don't know how to use LinQ for do that:

```
    public static int GetDepartmentID(int userID, Guid siteID, Guid webID)
    {
        int departmentID = 0;
        try
        {
            SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webID))
                    {
                        // Se obtiene el ID del grupo del usuario
                        SPUser usuario = web.SiteUsers.GetByID(userID);

                        //Se obtiene el departamento asociado a ese grupo de usuario
                        SPList listaDepartamentos = site.RootWeb.Lists[Properties.Listas.DEPARTAMENTOS];
                        SPListItemCollection listItemCollectionDepartamentos = listaDepartamentos.Items;

                        foreach (SPListItem listItemDepartamentos in listItemCollectionDepartamentos)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < usuario.Groups.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToInt32(listItemDepartamentos["IDCreador"]) == usuario.Groups[i].ID)
                                {
                                    departmentID = listItemDepartamentos.ID;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch
        { throw; }
        return departmentID;
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: LINQ is generally not faster than direct coding unless you are being inefficient. It is often shorter and for some, clearer. Why do you need it to be faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `foreach/for` loops with LINQ:

```
var userIDs = new HashSet<Int32>(usuario.Groups);
departmentID = listItemCollectionDepartamentos.First(listItemDepartamentos => userIDs.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(listItemDepartamentos["IDCreador"]))).ID;
```